# Problema ao consumir Json com javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Eu estou tentando consumir esse link

http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1

com esse metodo:

```
$.getJSON("http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1",   function (json) {
    alert(1);
});
```

Mas ele não lê.. eu testei com outros sites e funcionou. Eu tenho que chamar algum outro método ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o servidor/página de onde estás a tentar consumir os dados não tem qualquer autorização, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, de enviar os dados para o servidor que está a requisita-los com o pedido ajax... Ou seja, o problema não está na requisição (ajax) mas sim na API requisitada, que não aceita responder a pedidos ajax vindos de outros domínios.

Erro na consola:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Para resolveres, partindo do princípio que tens acesso ao código do lado servidor da api, tens de autorizar todos ou só alguns domínios a obterem a resposta certa, dependendo da linguagem do lado servidor podes dar esta autorização, no caso de ser php:

no topo do script php requisitado podes:

autorizar todos:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

autorizar só alguns, neste caso o domínio `exemplo1.com` e `exemplo2.com` estão autorizados a receber via ajax os dados:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.exemplo1.com', false);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.exemplo2.com', false);
```